# Commutator of $\hat {L}_x$ and $\hat{V}(\hat{r})$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, symmetry, commutator

Consider the angular momentum operator $\hat{L_x}=\hat y\hat{p}_z-\hat{z}\hat{p}_y$ and the potential operator $\hat{V}$ where the potential $\hat{V}=\hat{V}(\hat{r})$ is spherically symmetric.

It can be shown that $[\hat {L}_x, \hat {V}] = \hat y [\hat {p}_z, \hat V]-\hat z [\hat {p}_y, \hat V]. $ I tried showing this myself and found that this is only true if $$[\hat y, \hat V]=0  $$ and $$[\hat z, \hat V]=0. $$

Why are the last two equations equal to zero?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular momentum squared and Hamiltonian?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/389109/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the operator $\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}$ is just

$$\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}\psi=\boldsymbol{r}\psi$$

and similarly

$$\hat{V}(\hat{\boldsymbol{r}})\psi=V(\boldsymbol{r})\psi$$

*i.e.* simply multiplication with a real number. And as you know, real numbers are commutative.